# How to configure standalone HornetQ along with EAP 6.3 or Jboss 7 for durable JMS subscription?

Tags: jboss, jms

I would like to send JMS messages from one Jboss server to another but through a standalone HornetQ server.
This way I can have messages delivered later in case of the destination server crash (provided durable subscriptions).

However I have already messages routed internally at each Jboss. I would like a configuration that will not conflict with those.

The topology of the desired solution is visualised on the diagram.

[image]

How to achieve this configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Lets start from configuring the standalone HornetQ. You download the standalone server from their [download page](http://hornetq.jboss.org/downloads).
Next you have to configure the topic. Please add your topic in `%HORNETQ-HOME%\config\stand-alone\non-clustered\hornetq-jms.xml` file:

```
<topic name="Topic1">
   <entry name="java:/topic/Topic1"/>
</topic>
```

You probably want to test the configuration on one machine first, so I recommend changing the port at which HornetQ will be listening for messages from 5455 to 5456. 
Please edit `%HORNETQ-HOME%\config\stand-alone\non-clustered\hornetq-configuration.xml` file to change these ports. You also want to be able to register durable subscribers, so add these two lines to the `<security-setting match="#">` element in the same file:

```
<permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
<permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
```

Then start the standalone HornetQ by running `%HORNETQ-HOME%\run.bat`.

First we gonna see how to send a message to this newly created topic. For this we need a designated connection factory on the *Jboss Server 1*. In the `jboss:domain:messaging` subsystem of `%JBOSS-HOME1%\standalone\configuration\standalone-full.xml`, please add a new pooled connection factory:

```
<pooled-connection-factory name="StandaloneHornetQConnectionFactory">
    <transaction mode="xa"/>
    <connectors>
        <connector-ref connector-name="standalone-hornetq-connector"/>
    </connectors>
    <entries>
        <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/StandaloneHornetQConnectionFactory"/>
    </entries>
</pooled-connection-factory>
```

From now on you have to use this connection factory when you want to send a message to *Topic 1*. This is usually done by dependency injection:

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/exported/jms/StandaloneHornetQConnectionFactory")
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
```

As you can see above we referenced `standalone-hornetq-connector` but don't have one yet. Lets create it by adding another netty connector into `<connectors>`:

```
<connectors>
    <netty-connector name="standalone-hornetq-connector" socket-binding="standalone-hornetq-socket"/>
    <netty-connector name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>
    <netty-connector name="netty-throughput" socket-binding="messaging-throughput">
        <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
    </netty-connector>
    <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
</connectors>
```

As you can see we need `standalone-hornetq-socket` socket binding. Lets create it in `<socket-binding-group>` subelement:

```
<outbound-socket-binding name="standalone-hornetq-socket">
    <remote-destination host="localhost" port="5446"/>
</outbound-socket-binding>
```

As you can see, this is an outbound socket binding that will be used to send messages to our *HornetQ Standalone* server that is listening on the 5446 port. This configuration is enough on *Jboss Server 1* to send messages to *Jboss Server 2* via the *Standalone HornetQ* server.

To be able to receive the messages on *Jboss Server 2*, we have to once again repeat above configuration in the `%JBOSS-HOME1%\standalone\configuration\standalone-full.xml`. However this time we offset the ports of the *Jboss Server 2* by `port-offset:3`, to be able to work on the same machine:

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:3}">
```

This step is not nesessary if you will be putting the servers in the separate machines (If you do, please change `localhost` accordingly ;) ).

Now we can create MDB that will be a durable subscriber of the *Topic 1*.

```
@MessageDriven(name = "MyDurableSubscriber", activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Topic"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "java:/topic/Topic1"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "subscriptionDurability", propertyValue = "Durable"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "subscriptionName", propertyValue = "Topic1Subscription"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "clientId", propertyValue = "MySubscriber"),
})
@ResourceAdapter("StandaloneHornetQConnectionFactory")
public class MyDurableSubscriber implements MessageListener {
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The `@ResourceAdapter("StandaloneHornetQConnectionFactory")` line is the most important, because by default all MDBs are using `hornetq-ra` resource adapter to subscribe (local subscription). The `ResourceAdapter` annotation is from `org.jboss.ejb3.annotation` package
and you can make this class available to you via maven dependency:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.ejb3</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-ejb3-ext-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

With these all set you can enjoy durable subscriptions with "star" topology of your servers.

Comment: Could you please tell java program which connects to HornetQ. I have worked with JBoss messaging and in that we first mention properties (Jnp url/1099 and then NamingContextFactory and add properties to initial context and initalize connection factory. But unable to do same with default Configuration. Could you please suggest?

Comment: @zbig Do you have some examples sending messages to queue in jboss eap 6.3 or 6.4? Thanks.

Comment: @Makudex I have an example. Its is similar to lots of examples out there. I don't want to extend this answer because it is about configuration. Can you ask a new question so I can provide you with the example?

Comment: Thanks for the response @zbig .. I just wanted to ask instead where can I find the messages sent in jboss-eap 6.4? if there is.

Comment: @Makudex Don't quite understand. Do you want to see message log - what messages have been sent?

Comment: Yes that's what I want to see. I've built a simple hornetq jms that sends and at the same time it receives. But I don't know where to find the messages posted in jboss queue.

Comment: @Makudex Message logging can be turn on by setting `logger.org.hornetq.core.server.level=DEBUG` in the logging.properties file of HornetQ. This is only way I found by far.